# next operator not working as expected on rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs

Hello I try to caching http request but `.next()` operator not working if `cache` exists in `local storage`, here is example of my code

```
const APP_DATA = `app_data`;
const APP_VERSION = `app_version`;

@Injectable({ providedIn: `root` })

export class AppService {
    private _subject = new Subject();
    public appData$: Observable<any> = this._subject.asObservable();

constructor(
    private _http: HttpClient
) {
    const data = localStorage.getItem(APP_DATA);
    // const version = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(APP_VERSION));

    if (data) {
        this._subject.next(JSON.parse(data)); // <<<<<< here is a problem next operator not set data into appData$ observable
    }
    else {
        this.getAppData().subscribe();
    }
}

public clear(key: string) {
    localStorage.removeItem(key);
}

public getAppData(): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.get<any>(`${environment.apiURL}/v1/app_data`).pipe(
        switchMap(result => {
            this._subject.next(result.data);
            localStorage.setItem(APP_DATA, JSON.stringify(result.data));
            localStorage.setItem(APP_VERSION, JSON.stringify(result.data));
            return this.appData$;
        }),
        shareReplay()
    );
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values that are emitted, are only pushed to current subscribers.  In your case, it's impossible to have a current subscriber since you are calling next in the constructor of the service.

Late subscribers will not receive prior emissions.

However, you want late subscribers to receive prior emissions, you can use [`ReplaySubject`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/replaysubject) instead of plain `Subject`.

```
private _subject = new ReplaySubject(1);
```

This will automatically push the most recent emission to new subscribers.

Comment: Oh thank you very very much you save my day <3